# Retrieve purchased information in In-App purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created in-app purchase for non-consumable object  application in iPhone using with  store kit its properly working, but i am not getting that from which function information about product is checked that product is purchased or not.

please help me out

thnx
Kunal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to you to store information about successful purchases; you can use any of the standard means to persist information - `NSUserDefaults`, files in Documents, or SQLite/CoreData - or even retrieve data from your own web site, if that is appropriate.

You need to check for the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` value on each transaction in the delegate method: `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` in your `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`  handler, and store the data appropriately.